# iOS Facebook Audience Network SDK Crash - +[FBSDKTypeUtility dictionary:objectForKey:ofType:]:

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-audience-network

I've integrated Facebook Audience Network iOS SDK via Cocoapods.
`pod FBAudienceNetwork`

Cocoapods version: 1.9.3, FBAudienceNetwork version: 5.10.0

Then, I got many production iOS crashes due to `+[FBSDKTypeUtility dictionary:objectForKey:ofType:]:` unrecognized selector sent to class `FBSDKTypeUtility`. Looking at Crashlytics, FAN's `-[FBAdsManagerImpl cacheAdController:]` calls this unrecognized method.

Even though I have the latest Facebook SDKs installed via the latest Cocoapods, I'm getting a lot of crashes.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [FBAudienceNetwork 5.10.0 Podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/2/1/5/FBAudienceNetwork/5.10.0/FBAudienceNetwork.podspec.json), it only requires:

```
"FBSDKCoreKit/Basics": [
      ">= 5.6.0"
    ]
```

In [FacebookSDK 5.6.0](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk), `+[FBSDKTypeUtility dictionary:objectForKey:ofType:]:` is not implemented. This method is only implemented later in [FacebookSDK 7.0.1](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/commit/84e654828ac2ee57993586fa1f4a3275d7025700).

Therefore, the fix is to update [FBAudienceNetwork 5.10.0 Podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/2/1/5/FBAudienceNetwork/5.10.0/FBAudienceNetwork.podspec.json) to require:

```
"FBSDKCoreKit/Basics": [
      ">= 7.0.1"
    ]
```

Comment: While this works, the issue has been fixed in v5.10.1

Answer (score 1):

You can update Facebook Audience Network SDK to 5.10.1
version https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/changelog-ios/